# How do I unit-test a dynamic library using gcov?

Tags: c, unit-testing, gcc, gcov

I am building a dynamically-linked library, and am setting up a simple test suite. I want to use gcov to generate a static code analysis coverage report.

My library is a C file containing function implementations and a header file containing function prototypes. My test suite is simply an application that calls the functions in various ways and confirms the validity of the output.

I am compiling both the library and the test suite with the `-fprofile-arcs` and `-ftest-coverage` flags, as described [on GNU's guide to GCOV](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-Gcov.html#Invoking-Gcov). I am also including the `-O0` flag to disable compiler optimization and the `-g` flag to enable debug symbols. The executable generated from the test suite is linked dynamically to the library.

All files compile cleanly and without warning, but it fails to link the test suite to the library -- citing a "hidden symbol `__gcov_merge_add`". If I compile without the `-fprofile-arcs` and `-ftest-coverage` flags, the linking succeeds and I am able to run the test suite executable.

So I have a few questions which still aren't resolved after reading the GNU guide to GCOV.

1. Why is the linking failing? How can I resolve this?
2. Do I need to include the profile and coverage flags when compiling *both* the library and the test suite?

---

Here is my `inc/mylib.h` file:

```
#ifndef __MYLIB_H__
#define __MYLIB_H__

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif /* __cplusplus */

int
foo (int a);

int
bar (int a);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif /* __cplusplus */

#endif /* __MYLIB_H__ */
```

---

Here is my `src/mylib.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mylib.h"

int foo(int a) {
    if (a > 5) {
        return 5;
    }
    return a;
}

int bar(int a) {
    if (a < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return a;
}
```

---

Here is my `test/unittests.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mylib.h"

void run_foo_tests() {
    int inputs[] = {3, 6};
    int expected_results[] = {3, 5};
    int i, actual_result;

    for ( i = 0; i < sizeof(inputs) / sizeof(int); i++ ) {
        actual_result = foo(inputs[i]);
        if (actual_result == expected_results[i]) {
            printf("Test %d passed!\n", i + 1);
        } else {
            printf("Test %d failed!\n", i + 1);
            printf("  Expected result: %d\n", expected_results[i]);
            printf("  Actual result: %d\n", actual_result);
        }
    }
}

void run_bar_tests() {
    int inputs[] = {3, -1};
    int expected_results[] = {3, 0};
    int i, actual_result;

    for ( i = 0; i < sizeof(inputs) / sizeof(int); i++ ) {
        actual_result = bar(inputs[i]);
        if (actual_result == expected_results[i]) {
            printf("Test %d passed!\n", i + 1);
        } else {
            printf("Test %d failed!\n", i + 1);
            printf("  Expected result: %d\n", expected_results[i]);
            printf("  Actual result: %d\n", actual_result);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    run_foo_tests();
    run_bar_tests();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is my `Makefile`:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -std=c89 -g -O0 -Iinc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage

all: clean build run_tests

build:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -c src/*.c -o lib/mylib.o
    $(CC) -shared lib/mylib.o -o lib/libmylib.so
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) test/*.c -o bin/unittests -Llib -lmylib

run_tests:
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=lib bin/unittests
    gcov src/*.c

clean:
    rm -f *.gcda *.gcno *.gcov
    rm -rf bin lib ; mkdir bin lib
```

---

When I run `make`, I am presented with this output:

```
rm -f *.gcda *.gcno *.gcov
rm -rf bin lib ; mkdir bin lib
gcc -Wall -std=c89 -g -O0 -Iinc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -fPIC -c src/*.c -o lib/mylib.o
gcc -shared lib/mylib.o -o lib/libmylib.so
gcc -Wall -std=c89 -g -O0 -Iinc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage test/*.c -o bin/unittests -Llib -lmylib
/usr/bin/ld: bin/unittests: hidden symbol `__gcov_merge_add' in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/libgcov.a(_gcov_merge_add.o) is referenced by DSO
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Comment: You really should not use ancient ANSI-C. At least use C99, better standard C.

Comment: i need the library to be c89 compliant because of the obscure platforms i will be delivering to. is that relevant to gcov's operation?

Comment: (obviously the *real* library is more complicated than what i've posted here. this is just the MCVE version.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give the command line argument `-lgcov` for the linker (normally `-ftest-coverage` implies `-lgcov`, but you have a separate linking step where `-ftest-coverage` is not given as a command line argument).  Alternatively, you can just use the `--coverage` command line argument, which is a shortcut also for `-fprofile-arcs` and `-ftest-coverage`, as explained here: http://www.univ-orleans.fr/sciences/info/ressources/webada/doc/gnat/gcc_3.html:

> --coverage
>
> This option is used to compile and link code instrumented for
>   coverage analysis. The option is a synonym for `-fprofile-arcs'
>   `-ftest-coverage' (when compiling) and `-lgcov' (when linking). See
>   the documentation for those options for more details.

At the same place, btw., it is also explained that you don't have to compile all files with these options, which hopefully answers your question 2.

Comment: i've tried replacing the two compile flags with `--coverage` and the error persists. according to the page you linked, the `-ftest-coverage` already implied `-lgcov`.

Comment: if i change the CFLAGS variable in my makefile to use `--coverage` rather than the two flags i was originally using *and* add the `-lgcov` option to the linking step, it successfully builds and links the program but when trying to run gcov it says "mylib.gcno:cannot open graph file".

Comment: it seems to be storing the libmylib.gcno and libmylib.gcda files in the lib folder, although the unittest.gc** files are in the root directory.

Comment: aha! in the end, here's my working makefile: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8facc7db1ad9d047be63. if you update your answer with the changed options, i'll gladly mark it as accepted. namely, i didn't need to add any options when compiling the test suite, and needed the -o when running gcov.